# How to get values of a full <tr> tag in javascript after on change?

Tags: javascript, html-table, onchange

I have created a table inside javascript, with 3 input tags

- item_name,
- item_value and
- quantity.

On change quantity input tag, i want to get the values of all 3 input tags in that particular row to calculate the quantity. How to get the full data of `<tr>` ?

This is my table,

```js
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");

let key = entry[0];
let value = entry[1];

const item_name = document.createElement("input");
item_name.setAttribute("id", "item_name[]");
item_name.setAttribute("name", "item_name[]");
item_name.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
item_name.value = key;

td.appendChild(item_name);
tr.appendChild(td);
//$('#receipt_details').append(item_name);


const item_value = document.createElement("input");
item_value.setAttribute("id", "item_value[]");
item_value.setAttribute("name", "item_value[]");
item_value.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
item_value.value = value.amount;
//$('#receipt_details').append(item_value);
td.appendChild(item_value);
tr.appendChild(td);

const quantity = document.createElement("input");
quantity.setAttribute("id", "quantity[]");
quantity.setAttribute("name", "quantity[]");
quantity.value = 1;
//$('#receipt_details').append(quantity);

td.appendChild(quantity);
tr.appendChild(td);
tbody.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(tbody);
$('#receipt_details').append(table);

const total_column = document.createElement("input");
total_column.setAttribute("id", "total_cost[]");
total_column.setAttribute("name", "total_cost[]");
                
total_column.value = Number(value.amount) * 1;
                
td.appendChild(total_column);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="receipt_details"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please supply the `entry` var - but why use DOM when you have jQuery

Comment: I am so sorry , but how to proceed? @mplungjan

Comment: Show us more code  - add example data using the entry var you must have. Also if you have more than one row as I expect, you cannot hove the same ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `input` event like the following way:

```js
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");

let key = 'some key';
let value = {amount:'100'};

const item_name = document.createElement("input");
item_name.setAttribute("id", "item_name[]");
item_name.setAttribute("name", "item_name[]");
item_name.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
item_name.value = key;

td.appendChild(item_name);
tr.appendChild(td);
//$('#receipt_details').append(item_name);


const item_value = document.createElement("input");
item_value.setAttribute("id", "item_value[]");
item_value.setAttribute("name", "item_value[]");
item_value.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
item_value.value = value.amount;
//$('#receipt_details').append(item_value);
td.appendChild(item_value);

const quantity = document.createElement("input");
quantity.setAttribute("id", "quantity[]");
quantity.setAttribute("name", "quantity[]");
quantity.value = 1;

const total_column = document.createElement("input");
total_column.setAttribute("id", "total_cost[]");
total_column.setAttribute("name", "total_cost[]");
                
total_column.value = Number(value.amount) * 1;               
td.appendChild(total_column);
tr.appendChild(td);

td.appendChild(quantity);
tr.appendChild(td);
const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
tbody.appendChild(tr);
const table = document.createElement("table");
table.appendChild(tbody);
$('#receipt_details').append(table);

$('table input').on('input', function(){
  var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
  var value = parent.find('[name="item_value[]"]').val();
  var amount = parent.find('[name="quantity[]"]').val();
  var total_cost = value * amount;
  parent.find('[name="total_cost[]"]').val(total_cost);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="receipt_details"></div>
```

Comment: hey thanks alot!! its working fine. But how to add the value to input tag quantity? $(this).prev('[name="quantity[]"]').val() = total_cost; ?

Comment: @RhugvedaDesai, pass the value to `val()` like `$(this).prev('[name="quantity[]"]').val(total_cost);`

Comment: This  => $(this).prev('[name="total_cost[]"]').val(total_cost);  doesn't change the value of "total_cost" input tag

Comment: @RhugvedaDesai, you do not have any input with `[name=total_cost]` in your code, if exists, using inside `$('table input').on('input', function(){.....` should logically work. I will request you to update the question stating the problem if possible. You can also ask a new question:)

Comment: I have a new column total_cost[]. I have updated my question with the new code

Comment: and if i try to print console.log($(this).prev('[name="total_cost[]"]').val()); it gives me the value as undefined @Mamun

Comment: @RhugvedaDesai, the position where you are appending the `total_cost` will not be added to the table. Also, notice the changes in using the `closest()` to find the parent `tr` and then `find()` the specific element. Please see the updated answer":)

Comment: yeah cool! it's working fine now ! I have one more question , How to use keyup and keydown functions in place of  on change for this ==>  $('table input').on('input', function(){?

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $('tr').text();
```

if you can give id or class to the tr then it will be like e.g ( ) then it will be like

```
var value = $('#tablerow').text();
```

Comment: Does `text()` get the values of input elements?

Comment: No for input elements value works. for e.g
let theText = myTextInput.value;

Comment: The question is asking to get the values of the input elements of each row. So how does this post answer that question?

Comment: @HereticMonkey sorry brother, i didn't read the question properly i read the last part which confused me  How to get the full data of <tr> ?
It's my bad. Please do the needful to remove my answer. I am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftk1qj0m/1/)

```
quantity.onchange = function(e) {
  var row = {};
    $(e.target).closest('tr').find("input:text").each(function() {
    row[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
  });
  console.log(row);
}
```

Comment: Answers which explain changes made to code are less often downvoted than those which just show some code, the bulk of which is on another site.